# No implementation found for native

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, native

I have a test project that works good. I tried to use the native library from there (and the same methods) in my other project and I get this error :

```
W/dalvikvm(22240): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/myapp/Serial;.open:(Ljava/lang/String;IIZ)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
```

this is the JNI code in Serial class:

```
// JNI
    private native static FileDescriptor open(String path, int baudrate,
                int flags, boolean flowCon);
    public native void close();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test_lib");
    }
```

and I have "libtest_lib.so" in three folders in my libs folder : armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86.

I debugged the app and it seems the 'System.loadLibrary' is ineed called before the call of native method 'open'. So I can't see other options for the error..

Comment: if I am not mistaken, the method signature don't match.

Comment: but I used the same method(copy-pasted it) and the same library.. so how can that be?

Comment: I mean the same as in other project where it worked..

Comment: It didn't find `Serial.open()` in your library. Are you using explicit or implicit registration? How is it declared? Try listing the symbols from your library with `nm` to see the actual strings. See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries

Answer (score 1):

You probably copied and pasted from another project redefine your prototype in you c file as Java_Pacakage_JavaParentClass_functionName(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)